# Where can I find the up to date F# Core Library reference?

Tags: f#

It appears [current F# documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/)  is missing the core library. The only documentation I could find [looks quite dated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/fsharp-core-library-reference) and is from 2017. I spent a surprising amount of time (this being 2020 and F# being around for a while now) with google searches, trying to find the documentation for FSharpValue.MakeUnion method and could not find anything useful that appears to be from the horse's mouth.

Searching for a method the above method name in MS's documentation produces the following result (and all results on Ms docs link also leads to nothing):

[image]

Where should I be looking?

Comment: Same question here. It seems Microsoft is in the progress of moving the documentation to a new site.

Comment: I'm guessing they should eventually end up in [dotnet/docs/fsharp](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/tree/master/docs/fsharp)

Comment: The comments are correct. In 2016, Microsoft set out to migrate all their documentation of tens of millions of documents to "docs" and froze the existing docs. Late 2019 they weren't finished yet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamblog/msdn-technet-migration. There are also several issues on Github that complain about this. It is not specific to F#. All the F# team can do is wait until they greenlight that the documentation is moved. Meanwhile, docs _are_ being developed on Github, it is quite hard to find and yet incomplete and unpublished. I share your frustration.

Comment: A good place to ask questions is the #beginner's channel on Slack, it's quite active, see https://fsharp.org/guides/slack/. Here on SO, of course, and request documentation on Github to push the powers that be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The F# API docs are now located at: https://aka.ms/fsharp-core-reference (which currently just redirects to https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/).

For example FSharpValue.MakeUnion can be found at: https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-reflection-fsharpvalue.html#MakeUnion